# How to get auto response when we got query from user using php?

Tags: javascript, php, auto-responder

I have created one whatsApp chat bot using `chat api` ,It is working fine ,I am getting the messages and I can send messages also ,but I got one challenge here if user send message I should give auto reponse like if user send like `Hello` then I should give auto response like`Hello ,how are you` .

It is like `Siri or google Assist` how they are responding.

How can I do this challenge, kindly give any suggestion on it .

What I tried:

I have created one table in MYSQL called `FAQ` and columns are like `id,question and Ans.`,

```
**id**          **question**              **Ans**
1          hi                              hi,how are you?
2          hello                           hi, how are you?
3          what is price of shoe           52000/-
4          may I know the price of shoe    52000/-
5          Is 8 size show availabel?        Yes
```

Here if user send message like `what is price of shoe` then he will get response like `52000/-` but if user send message like `what is shoe price or  hat is price of shoe? (added ? extra)`
I am unable send response beacuse I am Matching exatly words .

How can over come this challenge , for that can I use any librarie of `php or javascript`,please suggest .

I have gone through this page `https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-language-search.aspx/` but it happening what I expected .

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Use words instead of whole sentences, i mean if the sentence of the user contains words like price then write a detailed response to that question.

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad I tried that 'natural language processing' from this link https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-language-search.aspx/, I followed all the instruction i did my query like ```SELECT `question` FROM `FAQ` WHERE MATCH(`question`) AGAINST('hello')``` I am getting emty record .